# Is this an accurate way to count page hits?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$hitcounter = ('/**************/hits.txt');
$hits = file($hitcounter);
$hits[0] ++;
$fp = fopen($hitcounter , "w");
fputs($fp , "$hits[0]");
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I added this to the top of a few pages on a website I run yesterday, and today when I checked it, it was at 25,000 and steadily rising.
Is this a rational number? Is this a good way to monitor page hits?

Comment: Race condition can appear here, so it's not accurate.

Comment: Just install google analytics

Comment: @CarlosAllende Have you tried it yet?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a good way to monitor page hits?

I would say **no**. Database based approach would provide nice & easy features to analyze the hits and do accounting on them (e.g. store hit time and later on do `SELECT ... WHERE DATE(hit_date) = '2015-06-18'` . It could be achieved via file based approach but would be an overkill.

Comment: is it acurate? 30k hits in one day seems excessive

Comment: Well, I just made 1.5 in 30 seconds (refreshing). You just have to notice that it will be triggered on every request - regular gets, ajax calls, etc. So, I guess it can sum up to...